# How to rename an action strip (for appending)

Tags: animation, actions

I created an animation in the NLA. Here I renamed the action, but whenever I'm appending the action, this name is not visible anymore.

In this example, I renamed the action itself to 'Talking', but below you'll see the Action Clip is still named 'ArmatureAction.003'.

[image]

How to rename the 'ArmatureAction.003' ?

Comment: There is a distinction between Strip name and Clip name.  I think you are wanting to rename the Clip?  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not easy to do in that view, but... In an *Outliner* Editor, chose the *Blender File* view, and look for this in the *Actions* list.  Select your ArmatureAction.003 and F2 (RMB: rename) and edit away.
[image]

Comment: This solved the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Simpler still, select the Action in the Dope Sheet/Action Editor and just click on it's name there to rename it.

If you're in the Tweak mode (Tab) from an NLA strip already, then it will be the selected Action in the Dope/Action Editor.